# Why is my jQuery breaking when I move my mouse really fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, break

I have made some hover states the show a div on hover of an element. It works really nice although if I move my mouse a few times quickly over it then it seems to break and the div no longer shows until i refresh the page.

Any ideas what might cause this as it has me baffled.

```
$('#s2_coffeetable').hover(function() {
    $('#popup1').stop().animate({
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }, 5)
}, function() {
    $('#popup1').stop().animate({
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }, 5)
});
$('#s2_drinks').hover(function() {
    $('#popup2').stop().animate({
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }, 100)
}, function() {
    $('#popup2').stop().animate({
        opacity: 'toggle'
    }, 100)
});
```

Comment: You are not using `.stop(true, true)` so the opacity is left to a progress state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `.stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] )` [jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)...

```
.stop(true, true)
```

Pass these 2 parameters to stop function.

Comment: that fixed it! I will 'answer' once im allowed. What did that do to fix it?

Comment: I've given you the reference link. clearQueue A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.
jumpToEndA Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to false.